# Looping over SQL files in directory

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, task

I've always thought that looping over sql files in directory in SSIS is easy... But I've got a problem today:
Execute SQL Task isn't executing statements that are in the sql file.
In the sql file I've got delete statement and then insert statement. 
SSIS Execute SQL Task component is done after about 2 sec, while executing the same script manually takes usually about 2 minutes, and of course in SSIS it doesn't insert anything.
I checked variable value that is coming from Foreach loop (with full filemane path) and it is ok.
I've got parametrized (by Expression) File Connection with this variable.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `GO` after each call within your SQL file?

Example:

```
// Your insert TSQL code here
GO
// Your delete TSQL code here
GO
// Etc...
```

It will not continue if you don't have this.

Comment: No, I don't. I see that if I create File Connection Manager and point to one file it works. But when I put variable from loop into Connection String by Expression it won't go...

Comment: You need to go over an example of using for each loop, or you need to do more troubleshooting and post back. i.e. after the first step into the loop, has it found your file and has ir populated variables as expected?

Comment: I've gone over an example - but it still doesn't work... Yes, after setting breakpoint on the loop it is populating variable with correct filepath (but wiht doubled \\ ex. C:\\SQL\\elo.sql